# Proper formatting of sql query with LIKE clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, jdbc, clojure, sql-like

I have an SQL query with a LIKE clause that uses the `%` wildcard. 
I have read that LIKE clauses can be problematic, like here: http://githubengineering.com/like-injection/.
But I am not sure if there would be a performance difference between the two different function calls below for certain user-inputs (although the query is essentially the same), and if the difference between them is related to what is talked about in the link.

I expected that a call to the first function would only return results like "&my-query%", so literally the user's input sorounded by two percent signs, but that is not the case.

```
(query db ["SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value LIKE ?"
       (str "%" user-input "%")])

(query db ["SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value LIKE '%' ? '%']"
       user-input])
```

Comment: Any string concatenation involving user input to build SQL is a security risk - always use prepared statements to set user supplied parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query looks safe to me. The second looks like invalid SQL. It looks like you are trying to do this:

```
(query db ["SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')"
   user-input])
```

which is also safe.

An unsafe query would embed the user input directly into the SQL string like this:

```
(query db [(str "SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE some_value LIKE '%" user-input "%'")])
```

Comment: You're right about the second query. I actually meant `...  LIKE '%' + ? + '%' ...` which is equivalent to your version.